# Mercurial merge permissions

Tags: mercurial, permissions, merge

Can you configure Mercurial permissions so only repository 1.1 can be merged into 1.0 and that other repositories (ie: 1.2, 1.3) can NOT be merged into 1.0?  We were interested in adding some controls around what can be merged into what.

Comment: I think that's quite a good idea -- but do you really mean 'repository' and not branch? Also wouldn't it be more useual to merge 1.0 (i.e. the branch you are doing maintenance work on) to 1.1 (i.e. the branch you are doing new features on). I don't think there's a trivial way to do this -- you could wrap hg in a shell script which checked the arguments to `hg merge`.

Comment: @tdavies, yes, repositories as opposed to branches..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My other answer addresses the named branches case, in which you have a few (not very great) options because the branch name is a part of the changeset and you can watch for changesets created initially on the 1.2 branch being merged into the 1.0 branch.

### The Clones As Branches Case

If you're working with **clones as branches** (my preferred work mode) the "what branch was this changeset done on" information isn't available.  What you could do, however, to put a `pretxnchangegroup` hook in the 1.0 repository that blocks the first changeset that you created in your 1.2 branch.  Then if anyone tries to push 1.2 stuff into the 1.0 central(-ish) repository their push will be denied.

Here's an example of how to do that sort of hook: http://ry4an.org/unblog/post/mercurial_changeset_blacklist/

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Why do you think this is a bad idea?

Comment: It just smacks of using a technical solution when a human one is better.  Kamil shows that someone can easily circumvent the check if they really want to, so you're only guarding against accidents, not malice.  If no one should be updating 1.0 just switch it to read-only, and if some people should be (bugfixes) then just set up the notify extension to email the team when it gets a changeset and everyone will jump on the offender.  Undoing a bad push is easy as typing `hg rollback` if you catch it right away.

Comment: Sure, and in the end it's a matter of preference.  Some people like handguns with a mechanical safety, and some people think it makes you less safe because you're less careful around the trigger.  At least a merge error is way easier to undo than a gun error.

Answer (score 5):

### The Named Branches Case

You can't stop people from doing whatever they want on their local machine (that's the decentralized part), but you can refuse to accept those changes with a `pretxnchangegroup` hook.  You'd need a hook that checks each incoming changeset to make sure that if it's a merge changeset (has two parents) that neither parent's branch violates your rules.

That's assuming you're talking about named branches.  If you're using repos as branches, bookmarks as branches, or anonymous branches that becomes harder since the branch name isn't part of the changeset.

If you're using Named Branches you can use the AclExtension to make certain branches writeable by only select users -- perhaps only the release manager gets to push/merge into 1.0 once active development is done?

In the end, no restriction you put in place will replace good employee training.

Comment: Not to mention that nothing prevents someone from using the transplant extension and just copying the equivalent changes in to the branch of their choice without performing a merge. Or any other manual methods, for that matter.

Comment: We are using repositories as branches..  what are the options with this model?  Maybe we should be using named branches..  is there a good doc that discusses named branches vs repos as branches?

Comment: Repositories as branches is my favorite work mode too (I'm not a fan of named branches, though they work fine), but it makes what you want to do almost impossible.  I'll add another answer that covers that case, but I'm saying up front it's a bad idea.